# size() working with Rcpp but not RcppArmadillo

Tags: r, rcpp

I created a class 'checkedVector' that worked fine. However, once I used RcppArmadillo that I needed for other functions my checkedVector is not working anymore. The function size() is no longer defined. Tried several namespace options but could not find a solution.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert> 

namespace br_stl 
{

template <class T>

class checkedVector : public std::vector<T>
{
public:

checkedVector()
{ }
checkedVector(size_t n, const T& value = T())
: std::vector<T>(n,value)
{ }
checkedVector(T* i, T* j)
: std::vector<T>(i,j)
{ }

T& operator [] (ptrdiff_t index)
{
 assert (index >= 0 && index < static_cast <ptrdiff_t> (size()));
 return std::vector<T>::operator[](index);
}
};
```

Comment: Use `.n_elem`. See [the documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I am sure that `.n_elem` is indeed the right function to get the size attribute. However, I need a little more help. I am not quite sure why  ptrdiaff_t has been converted using static_cast and if this is still necessary with `.n_elem`. Obviously I cannot simply replace size().

Comment: Try reordering the `#include` lines. You probably also do no need to include `vector`; unsure about `cassert`.

Comment: Maybe store the size when you construct the object. What are you trying to implement here? Please show us what you tried with RcppArmadillo.

Comment: Thanks Dirk that solved it! Any good reference on how to order the `#include` lines to avoid such confusions?! In this case I think I needed `vector` before `#include  <RcppArmadillo.h>`.

Comment: @SimeonLisovski Cannot think of a reference, it is essentially just hard-earned experience.  System-libraries first, other established libraries next, local headers last.